# how can I return the value using or operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I return or method something like this:

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).index(3) or $(this).index(6);
}).css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To filter the **4th and 7th** element, you need to:

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    return index === 3 || index === 6;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

To filter the **4th, 7th, 10th, ...** element, you could write:

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    return index > 0 && index % 3 === 0;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

To filter against a **whitelist of values**, you could use an array literal and [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/):

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    return $.inArray($(this).index(), [3, 6, 99, 100]) >= 0;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what the >=0 is checking.

Comment: `$.inArray` returns -1 if the searched value is not found; or a number >= 0 if searched value is found in the array.

Answer (score 2):

May be nth-child filter

```
$('div').filter(':nth-child(4), :nth-child(7)').css('color','red');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/erG7r/)

Comment: @NavinRauniyar see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/erG7r/3/ - for all elements in indexes like `4, 7, 10, 13....`(index starts with 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('body').append('<div>' + i + '</div>')
   }

   $('div').filter(function(){
    if($(this).index()== "3" || $(this).index()=="6")
    {
         $(this).css('color','red');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

The following will return index(3) if it is truthy; else it will return index(6)

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).index(3) || $(this).index(6);
}).css('color','red');
```